# Sharepoint Microsfot Flow: Reminder emails

Tags: email, reminder, microsoft-flow

I have a sharepoint list. In this list, each row contains some basic information like email address, yes/no field (fieldname - "issue_fixed").

I want to send a daily reminder email for each row where "issue_fixed" field is not checked(issue_fixed=No).

How to achieve this using Microsoft Flow?

Comment: Is there a specific question you have about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a flow that uses a timer as its trigger, and schedule the timer for once a day. After the trigger fires, have an action that gets the list items, filtered for the ones that need a reminder, and process those through a loop, sending the emails. Here is a [microsoft doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/flow/run-scheduled-tasks) that will walk you through the process of triggering a flow based on a schedule.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work, Problem was caused by O365 adding "_x200" to the column name. Once I added the _x0200 my filters work and I was able to complete my flow.